# Beautify Mix of PHP and HTML statement

Tags: php, ternary

I want to write this line in one outer php tag. May be we can use echo statement with concatination? Or someone can use ternary statement to beautify it?

```
<?php if ( condition = true ) { ?>

  <p ><label for="user_limit" > User - Limit(&euro;)</label ><input type = "text" name = "user_limit" id = "user_limit" size = "40" value = "<?php echo inout($res['user_limit']);?>" /></p >

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Seems like something you could have tried to do yourself, and then if you get a problem you could have asked whats wrong with my attempt

Comment: Why the ternary tag?

Comment: "May be we can use echo statement with concatination" [sic] ....yes you could but IMHO it'll probably end up less clear / readable / maintainable than it is now - you'll end up with more issues with escaping of quote marks etc for one thing, and the HTML layout will be less clear.

Comment: @ADyson Is my `echo` so unmanagable? If so I will delete it

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's a matter of personal preference I guess. Personally I wouldn't do it like that. I find it ugly, less readable etc, all the things I said above. You've had to make a change (single quotes for double quotes round the HTML attributes, which isn't a big deal but there are other places it can become more of a problem). But OP asked for it, so leave it there if you want. At least they know what the choice is now.

Answer (score 2):

Personaly I would not shorten your code because that would make it less readable, only thing I would change is using [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to make it easier to understand where the if statement stops like this:

```
<?php if ( condition = true ): ?>

  <p ><label for="user_limit" > User - Limit(&euro;)</label ><input type = "text" name = "user_limit" id = "user_limit" size = "40" value = "<?php echo inout($res['user_limit']);?>" /></p >

<?php endif; ?>
```

In my opinion using if/endif combo is more readable when combining html and php.

However if you want to make it more compact, at the expense of readibility you can use this one liner:

```
<?= ($condition) ? '<p ><label for="user_limit" > User - Limit(&euro;)</label ><input type = "text" name = "user_limit" id = "user_limit" size = "40" value = "' . $someVal . '" /></p>' : ''; ?>
```

Explanation:

```
// <?= is called short echo tag and it equals <?php echo
// ?: ternary operator is shorthand for if/else statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use an echo

```
<?php 
if ( $condition == true ) { 

    echo "<p>
            <label for='user_limit'> User - Limit(&euro;)</label>
            <input type='text' name='user_limit' id='user_limit' size='40' value='" 
                . inout($res['user_limit']) . "' />
          </p>";
}
```

> NOTE: Also removed a lot of unnecessary spaces in your HTML to keep it neat and tidy

Comment: forgot to mention that this will be displayed always, because of the assignment within the `if`(assuming `condition` is a real condition/variable, but not a `const`) :)

Comment: @mitkosoft Yea, I used the same Pseudo code as the OP provided :( Assuming they were aware of the fact that was not valid PHP, but as you mention it